# Space complexity of C++ STL containers

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have found various resources enlisting the time complexity of various C++ STL containers. Where can I find the space complexities which are involved with using C++ STL containers?

I do know that for most of the  containers the relationship is linear with respect to the number of elements contained. But what about containers which use a hash function? Is it possible to make any guarantees in that case?

Comment: The problem with that is, the standard defines the interfaces and from time to time the expected (upper bound) complexity on the containers. You may implement a map as a red-black or an avl tree for example, or any other map that is based on comparisons. So the answer would be: depends on the implementation.

Comment: I can't contribute anything helpful but would you mind adding the resources for the time complexity?

Comment: Destructor is required to run in linear time (23.2.1 Table 96). I think it implies linear size of the structure.

Comment: Time and space complexity relate to algorithm, not to data structures. For instance, the time complexity for searching an element in a vector is not the same as the time complexity for accessing an element of a vector by its address. Actually, I do not think any container takes an amount of memory not proportionnal to its number of elements. It could take twice the amount of memory used by a contiguous array, but not, e.g, that amount squared. So, either I am completely wrong or you need to point out what you really want.

Comment: @zch: No, there are data structures for which that doesn't necessarily hold. Admittedly, they're obscure. The dtor complexity is only measured in terms of operations on the element type, anything else is unaccounted for.

Comment: @zch: at the most absurd, nothing precludes `std::map` implementation that doubles the size of the allocated node on each allocation, and just lets the extra memory sit unused. Since the time to allocate or deallocate a block of memory doesn't depend on the size of that block (eventual disk thrashing aside), such an implementation would happily satisfy time complexity requirements.

Answer (score 2):

There's two sources of complexity bounds for every STL container. First one is what the standard mandates. A good (and almost always correct) source for that is cppreference.com, e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container if you don't have the standard itself. Second, things not specified in the standard are implementation defined. These implementations are mostly very efficient given their multi-purpose nature.

To answer your question with a short answer: Yes, you can expect linear space. But the details are a bit more complicated.

A quick look into the Standard (23.2.1 General container requirements) says:

> All of the complexity requirements in this Clause are stated solely in terms of the number of operations on the contained objects.

Section 23.2.5 (Unordered associative containers) states:

> The worst- case complexity for most operations is linear, but the average case is much faster.

The standard goes on and defines certain aspects of unordered associative containers in more detail. When looking carefully at the operation complexities, we can infer something for the space. Digging a bit further (23.5.4.2 unordered_map constructors) reveals:

> Constructs an empty unordered_map using the specified hash function, key equality func- tion, and allocator, and using at least n buckets. If n is not provided, the number of buckets is implementation-defined. Then inserts elements from the range [f, l). max_load_factor() returns 1.0. Complexity: Average case linear, worst case quadratic

Quadratic time happens for a pathologically bad hash function. The average case is what you should expect, namely linear time implies linear space. The worst case occurs when the hash map spills over and needs to be reconstructed (yes, handwaivingly speaking).

For element access, we get a similar thing:

> Complexity: Average case O(1), worst case O(size()).

Also, the standard says that the implementation has to use a bucketed data structure. Elements are hashed into buckets. These buckets will also need space and depending on the way you initialize the unordered_map, the number of buckets is implementation defined. So, efficient implementations will use O(n+N) space, where n is the number of elements and N the number of buckets.

Hope that clarifies things a bit.

Answer (score 1):

### Caution

I was looking for the answer to the space complexity of associative container `set`. Hope this helps.

The content below **partly** answered the question.

### Answer

#### Space Complexity of `set`

In this post [space complexity of stl set?](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/23062), due to the data structure of `set` (a red-black tree), the space complexity is usually **`O(n)`**

#### Space Complexity of `map`

The data structure of `map` and `set` are both red-black tree, so the space complexity of `map` is usually **`O(n)`**, but it depends on the real-world cases (see: 
 [space complexity of a map](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/91413/)).